# Using Rx Timeout with FromEventPattern Observer

Tags: c#, events, timeout, system.reactive

I'm trying to implement a timeout when there no events in a period if time.

Scenario:

I have an object that raises an event every time a message is received.
I would like to react when there are no messages (OnReceived events) received in a period of time (lets say, 20 secs)

This what I have so far

```
var observable =  Observable.FromEventPattern<BasicDeliverEventHandler>(
                             handler => _innerConsumer.Received += OnReceived,
                             handler => _innerConsumer.Received -= OnReceived);

var timeout = observable.Timeout(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20));
using (timeout.Subscribe(_ => { },
              exception => 
              Tracer.Warning("Eventing Consumer timeout : {0}", exception.Message)))
{ }
```

I'm creating an observable from a EventPattern. Then, using the timeout. What I don't understand is how to get the exception from the Timeout. I want to react when that´s happen.

I don't think the Subcribe method is the correct way, but that's I get from the docs.
  I'm open to suggestions or other alternatives if this is not the correct one.

Thanks in advance

Comment: There shouldn't be a `using` statement in your code. That's immediately canceling your subscription, which is preventing any of your notifications from reaching the observer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Timeout` is problematic because it terminates the sequence. `Throttle` is what you want - but you also need to insert a start element in case you get no events at all.

I convert the events to Unit.Default - this is useful when you don't care what happened, just that *something* happened - and use `StartWith` to seed the throttle:

```
var timeout = observable.Select(_ => Unit.Default)
                        .StartWith(Unit.Default)
                        .Throttle(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20);

var subs = timeout.Subscribe(_ => Console.WriteLine("Timeout!"));
```

Out of interest, I also have a similar solution to this for detecting disconnected clients - this time providing a single timeout notification for multiple sources: http://www.zerobugbuild.com/?p=230

Comment: I was thinking about adding `StartWith` to my answer, but as the consumer, I would like to have the original event. I guess it depends on how exactly the consumer is going to use the data.

Comment: OP didn't ask for it, but you can always seed Throttle with a *null object* instead, like `EventArgs.Empty`.

Comment: I didn't get the discussion around the StartWith. I would like to kill the

Comment: @Markust Can you rephrase that? I don't understand.

Comment: StartWith is required so that the stream will time out in the event of no events being raised at all- `Throttle` wouldn't work in that case because there would be no event to suppress.

Comment: Sorry, hit enter in the before finishing my thoughts. Anyway James figured it out what I meant. I case I don´t have any events, I will need to use the StartWith. Thank you guys.-

Comment: Your solution for disconnected clients is essential what I needed. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Let's take a look at the code you have.

```
var observable =
  Observable.FromEventPattern<BasicDeliverEventHandler>(
    handler => _innerConsumer.Received += OnReceived,
    handler => _innerConsumer.Received -= OnReceived
    );

var timeout = observable.Timeout(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20));

using (timeout.Subscribe(
  _ => { },
  exception =>
  Tracer.Warning("Eventing Consumer timeout : {0}", exception.Message)))
{

}
```

We can re-write the subscription logic like so:

```
var subscription = timeout.Subscribe(
  _ => { }
  exception =>
    Tracer.Warning("Eventing Consumer timeout : {0}", exception.Message)
  );

subscription.Dispose(); // This is bad
```

Since your subscription is being disposed of immediately, your observer isn't receiving an of the notifications you're expecting.

By removing `subscription.Dispose()`, or the `using` statement, your observer should receive a `TimeoutException` 20 seconds after subscribing. However, because `Exception`s also cancel subscriptions, you will only ever receive this `Exception` once.

Furthermore, the `Timeout` operator starts a timeout at the time of subscription, and does not cancel the timeout unless the subscription is cancelled, or the source observer completes.

You might want to try using a different operator, such as `Throttle`.

```
observable.Throttle(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20))
    .Subscribe(x =>
        Console.WriteLine("it has been 20 seconds since we received the last notification.")
        )
```